# IE9 showing IE7 User Agent

Tags: internet-explorer-9, user-agent

I am testing applications from VS2010 with IE9, all was working ok then all of a sudden the IE9 browsers decides strangely that it wants to be IE7. When I query navigator.userAgent, it comes up with the IE7 user agent. What's up with that?!

Now the IE9 keeps thinking it IE7. I've never used IE7 before!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes IE thinks a page will display better using an older Browser model or standard and will often switch to that. Press f12 and change the Browser mode and Document Mode back to IE9

Comment: Note this (IE reverting document mode) typically is a behavior exhibited when you have a missing or incorrect `DOCTYPE` or *MANY* html validation errors.

Comment: Thanks guys, now its back to normal.

Comment: ahhh IE, you're the gift that keeps on giving.